# Tomcat 7 ignoring my server.xml file (vhost)

Tags: java, xml, tomcat

I am running into a wall with the tomcat manuals.
I want to run two domains on the same server by using tomcat.
I was successfully changing the port 8080 to 80 in the server.xml
Then I wanted to configure the vhosts as its written on the apache tomcat page.
After spending days in it, I gave up and just moved the server.xml to an other place and saw that tomcat is not even taking care about that. Not even a single error in the log files.

Tomcat is installed at /etc/tomcat7 on an ubuntu server.
Other softwares are ip2ban and java8 - so nothing specially going on there.

Comment: Are you referring to this page? http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html

Comment: Are you using a standard Tomcat install (tar.gz) from the ASF or are you using a butchered pre-packaged version provided by your distro?

Comment: no i was using apt for that i think. i am also missing a catalina.xml as i was reading in the internet about it.